# qmake build from command prompt

Tags: qt, build, cmd, qmake, nmake

I need to have a cmd build script to address x86 x64 compilation issue associated with the IDE (i mean switching qt versions & rebuilding). The problem is that, in my .pro file, I add dependency on external library in this way:

```
LIBS += ../Libs/SomeExternal.lib
```

Now when I build this project from QtCreator, everything compiles and builds fine, but when I try to build using command prompt + qmake I get the following linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '../Libs/SomeExternal.lib'
```

I understand that this issue is related to paths, but I don't know how to let LINKER.exe see the location where my project is located. Just like QtCreator does.

I try to build using the following way:

- I run VS command prompt. I'm using MSVC compiler.
- I type qmake.exe -project C:\ProjectPath\Project.pro
- nmake

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
LIBS += -L$${PWD}/../Libs -lSomeExternal
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd):

> The PWD variable specifies the full path leading to the directory
>   containing the current file being parsed.

Comment: Thanks Dave, it worked fine, but only when I removed -L from your snippet. Could you please explain what -L stands for? I couldn't find anything about it. Thanks again :)

Comment: `-L` (capital L) defines a path in which to look for libraries. `-l` (lowercase l) defines the name of a library to link. See the section on "LIBS" in the documentation. (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)